# Running OctoPack to create nuget package containing DEBUG assemblies

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopack

How can I use OctoPack to create a nuget package contains the debug assemblies instead of the "release" version? It seem octopack 3.0 no longer support this command parameter /p:OctopusPackageConfiguration=Debug

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/97-is-there-a-way-to-use-octopack-to-build-for-other-configurations-than-release

Comment: My MSBUILD command is 'code' %NUGET_EXEC% restore "%WORKSPACE%\SpacePlanning.Api.sln"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "%WORKSPACE%\SpacePlanning.Api.sln" /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug /p:OctopusPackageConfiguration=Debug /p:RunOctoPack=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use extra /t:Rebuild /p:Debug  parameters instead of octopack commands. And you must include pdb file extensions to your csprojname.nuspec file which must have the same name with your csproject file name.